# Add new field to json object on each index in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I am trying to ping server IP from the JSON and add the response status on the same JSON. But the response status is not added. Below is my code and please advise

```
    var IP = [{
        "name": "Server 01",
        "serverip": "10.211.130.32"
    },
    {
        "name": "Server 02",
        "serverip": "10.211.130.33"
    }] 
      for (let host of IP) {
        let res = await ping.promise.probe(host.serverip, {
          timeout: 5 
      });  
      IP = {...IP, "status" : res.alive}
      } 
      console.log(IP)
```

What i get as output is

```
{
"0": {
    "name": "Server 01",
    "serverip": "10.211.130.32"
},
"1": {
    "name": "Server 02",
    "serverip": "10.211.130.53"
},
"status": true
```

}

Expecting the output like

```
[{
        "name": "Server 01",
        "serverip": "10.211.130.32",
        "status" : true
    },
    {
        "name": "Server 02",
        "serverip": "10.211.130.33",
        "status" : false
    }]
```

Comment: Is the issue fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for in` and also use IP[host] for the data.

what you were doing wrong was, you were replacing the entire IP with the IP and a new key `status` instead you will have to have the `status` within each object of IP

```js
var getStat = (ar) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ alive: true }), 1000);
  });
}

var func = async () => {
  var IP = [{
      "name": "Server 01",
      "serverip": "10.211.130.32"
    },
    {
      "name": "Server 02",
      "serverip": "10.211.130.33"
    }
  ] 

  for (let host in IP) {
    let res = await getStat(IP[host].serverip, {
        timeout: 5 
    });
    IP[host]['status'] = res.alive
  }

  console.log(IP)
}

func();
```

Comment: Thanks Adarsh for the reply. I tried and get the message - obj.toObject is not a function

Comment: Did you check the value of `res.alive` ?

Comment: Yes, it is returning true or false

Comment: I have updated the answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Also be sure to run the eniter for loop, including the `console.log(IP)` inside an `async` function. or else the `await` will not be useful

Comment: The entire function runs inside async function. updated code is not added the status field to the IP

Comment: I found the issue is with the input value IP. The data is received dynamically. I have corrected the IP value format and it works. Thank you very much for the support